# How to output a reverse expanded sum

Tags: java, sum, switch-statement

I want to output a **reverse expanded sum**, which should give me an output like this:

> **Reverse expanded sum**:
>   Output the expanded sum in reverse.
>   For example, if the user entered 7, then your program should output:
>
> ```
> 7+6+5+4+3+2+1=28
> ```

The code below is giving me an non-stop output instead with `+-12+-13` format:

```
 public static int printSum(int n, boolean reverse) {
    int sum = 0;
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i--) {
        sum += i;//was =
        //System.out.print(i + "+");
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <n; i--) {
        s =String.valueOf(i);
        System.out.print(s + "+");
    }
    //System.out.print(i);

    System.out.print( n + "=" + sum);
    return sum;
}
```

I used `case` statements in the `main` method to call the `printSum` method:

```
//reverse expanded sum
case 2: 
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer.\n");    
    number = console.nextInt();
    printSum(number, false);
    break;
```

Comment: I highly recommend Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" for advice on isolating bugs like this one.  It's one of several good articles listed at the bottom of the Help Center's "[ask]". The process of providing a [mcve] might have solved your problem before you even asked it.  (If nothing else, it probably would have revealed that you never actually _use_ the `reverse` parameter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this does what you linked in the image assuming it only takes positive integers given "Enter a positive integer.\n"

```
  public static int printSum(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
            sum += n - x;
            if(x != n - 1){
                System.out.print((n - x) + "+");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print((n - x) + "=" + sum);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose your logic is correct to some extent. Try this.

```
public static int printSum(int n, boolean reverse){

  int sum = 0;
  for( int i = n ; i>0 ; i--){
     sum += i;
     if(i > 1){
       System.out.print(i + "+");
     }else{
      System.out.print(i);
     }    
  }
  System.out.print( n + "=" + sum);
  return sum;
 }
```